# Snail animation in Gmail chat

Tags: gmail, google-hangouts

I resized the chat window, and this snail appeared (also with animation):

> [image]

Why did it appear? What's its significance?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think that the partner you chatted with typed: `/shydino` in his chat.

This is one of the [easter eggs](http://www.engadget.com/2013/05/17/hangouts-easter-eggs/) in Google Hangouts

Comment: That's really awesome. :-)